# For what values of $r$ is $f(x,y,z)$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

This was one of the problems in my textbook. I've tried searching for an answer but they are all blocked by a paywall! So I want to see if my approach is correct. The question asks:

> For what values of the number $r$ is the function
> $$f(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{(x+y+z)^r}{x^2+y^2+z^2} & (x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0) \\[1ex] 0 & (x,y,z) = (0,0,0) \end{cases}$$
> continuous on $\Bbb R^3$?

Here is my approach, is it correct? Keep in mind that this is a draft and I am aware that some parts may be unclear and require further justification. I just want to make sure that the general argument makes sense.

Let $\mathbf{r}(t)=\langle f(t), g(t), h(t) \rangle$ be the path that the point $(x,y,z)$ goes along as it approaches $(0,0,0)$. Thus, since $\mathbf{r} \neq \mathbf{0}$ the function becomes

$$
f(\mathbf{r}(t)) =\frac{(f(t)+g(t)+h(t))^r}{f(t)^2 + g(t)^2 + h(t)^2}
$$
Notice that if $\mathbf{r}(t) \neq \mathbf{0}$, then $f$ exists and the denominator in $f(x,y,z)$ is equal to $\|\mathbf{r}\|^2$. Also notice that $f(t)+g(t)+h(t) = \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \langle 1,1,1 \rangle$. This in turn is equivalent to $\|\mathbf{r}\| \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \cos\theta$. Thus $f$ becomes
$$
f(\mathbf{r}(t)) =\frac{\left(\|\mathbf{r}(t)\| \cdot\sqrt{3} \cdot \cos\theta\right)^r}{\|\mathbf{r}(t)\|^2}
$$
Let $t_0$ be the number such that $\mathbf{r}(t_0) = \mathbf{0}$. Recall that a function $f$ is continuous if $\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{a}} f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{a})$, so if $\lim_{t\to t_0} f(\mathbf{r}(t)) = 0$ then $f$ is continuous at $0$ ($f$ is already continuous anywhere else, assuming that it's defined there), which would imply that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $r<0$ then $f$ the limit cannot exist at $(0,0,0)$ (I will make this statement more exact in the real proof, I'm running out of time here). Thus it must be the case that $r>0$ so $(\sqrt{3} \cos\theta)^r$ must exist. So
$$
\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{\left(\|\mathbf{r}\| \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \cos\theta \right)^r}{\|\mathbf{r}\|^2} = (\sqrt{3}\cos\theta)^r \lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{\|\mathbf{r}\|^r}{\|\mathbf{r}\|^2}
$$

If we do the substitution $u=\|\mathbf{r}(t)\|$ ($u>0$ so the limit approaches $0$ from both sides, just think of it as $|x|$) then the limit is
$$
\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{u^r}{u^2} 
$$

It can be shown that (and I will show it in the real proof) if $r > 2$ then this limit exists and is equal to $0$. Therefore if $r>2$ then $f(x,y,z)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: It works but it is probably simpler to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality so you don't need to interoduce $r$ and $\theta$. Indeed, let $u = (1,1,1)$ and for all $v = (x,y,z)$, $|f(v)| = |\left<v,u\right>|^r/\|v\|^2 \leqslant \|u\|^r\|v\|^{r - 2} = 3^{r/2}\|v\|^{r - 2} \rightarrow 0$ if $r > 2$ and when $r \leqslant 2$, $f(tu) = t^r\|u\|^{2r}/\|tu\|^2 = 3^{r - 1}t^{r - 2} \not\rightarrow 0$ when $t \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It correct for me, but it easier to make a subtitution to spherical coordinates, you'll end up in a similar situation, $$\lim_{\rho\to 0}\frac{\rho^r g(\theta, \phi) ^r}{\rho^2}, $$ which gives you the convergence to $0$ when $r>2$, but that doesnt tell you anything about the case $0<r\leq 2$ , like in your case. So you still need to look for that case.